# Swing GUI encoding to read Amharic characters

Tags: java, swing

How to fix this code to read the amharic language?

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;`
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Gui {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () -> new Gui().start() );
    }

    public void start() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(" አማረኛ ");
        JButton btn = new JButton(" ስላም ");
        JButton btn2 = new JButton(" ሃይ");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        frame.getContentPane().add(btn);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btn2);
        frame.setSize(250, 220);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

[image: click this link the output look like this Image]

Comment: You may need to change the Look and Feels font to something which supports the character set you're trying to display - and/or use the system look and feel

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Unicode symbols. For ex:

```
JButton btn = new JButton(" \u1235\u120B\u137F ");
```

You can find those codes with a simple google search.
just try like this: "ሃ unicode"
Find the hex value (last 4 digits) of the code and add "\u" to the beginning.

Comment: This will not improve anything, unless the JButton's font supports these Amharic characters.